# No me realiza la suma de un array

Tags: c++, array

Veran, estando en mi clase me encuentro realizando un codigo que saca media moda y mediana
Ahora mismo me encuentro arreglando el programa para que unicamente me de una suma de un arreglo y de ahi pueda empezar a maniobrar y agregar el resto de operaciones
Unicamente requiero realizar la suma
El problema es que estoy trabajando con funciones amigas y a la hora de realizar la operacion unicamente me manda el primer dato escaneado

Ejemplo: Escribo que la longitud, cantidad de N datos es de 4, me deja escribir los 4 datos sin problema, pero a la hora de imprimir la suma solo me muestra el primer dato escrito, no me suma el resto :(

```
class DATOS{
        //Funciones amigas
        friend float MEDIA(DATOS &objdatos);
        friend float VARIANZA(DATOS &objdatos);
        friend float DESVIACION(DATOS &objdatos);
        friend float MEDIANA(DATOS &objdatos);
        friend float MODA(DATOS &objdatos);
        public:
        //Constructor
        DATOS(int num=1);
        //
        DATOS(DATOS& Original);
        //operador de asignacion
        void operator= ( DATOS &objdatos);
        
        //Destructor
        ~DATOS(void);
        //Asignacion de memoria para el vector dinamico
        void AsigMem(void);
        //
        int ObtN(void);
        float ObtD(void);
        //Impresion y Lectura
        void Leer_datos(void);
        void Imprimir(void);
    private:
        int N;//Tamaño de la muestra
        float *datos;//vector dinamico
};

DATOS::DATOS(int num){
    N=num;
    AsigMem();
}

DATOS::DATOS(DATOS &Original){
    N=Original.N;
    AsigMem();
    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
         datos[ i ] = Original.datos[ i ];
}
//
void DATOS::operator=(DATOS &objdatos){
    N=objdatos.N;
    AsigMem();
    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
         datos[ i ] = objdatos.datos[ i ];
}

DATOS::~DATOS(void){
    delete [] datos;
    datos=nullptr;
}

void DATOS::AsigMem(void){
    if(N==0)
    datos=nullptr;
    else
    datos=new float[N];
}
int DATOS::ObtN(void){
    return N;
}
float DATOS::ObtD(void){
    return datos[N];
}
void DATOS::Leer_datos(void){
   cout<<"Ingrese el numero de datos: ";
   cin>>N;
   for(int i;i<N;i++){
        cout<<"\n\tIngrese el dato #"<<i+1<<": ";cin>>datos[i];
    }
}

void DATOS::Imprimir(void){
    cout<<N<<"//";
    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        cout<<datos[i]<<endl;
}
float MEDIA(DATOS &objdatos){
    float suma=0;
    return (double) (suma+=*objdatos.datos);
}
```

Comment: ¿La función `MEDIA` es la que no está sumando bien? `suma += ...` no suma mágicamente todos los números del arreglo. Solo suma un número a la variable `suma` y lo guarda en ella. Usa un loop sumando cada uno de los elementos. Entiendo que seas nuevo, pero deberías repasar lo que sabes del lenguaje. Difícilmente trabajes con conceptos avanzados si no sabes lo básico.

Comment: Si, es la funcion **MEDIA** la que no esta sumando bien
Pero no comprendo, como que usar un loop?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Pues, si tienes un arreglo, debes recorrerlo como toda la vida para ir sumando el valor de cada elemento, no?

Comment: Un detalle rapido, el arreglo si lo imprime y registra bien, pero como dijo un chico mas arriba, solo suma un numero a la variable suma, no suma el resto
Solo quiero saber como hacer que sume el resto :((

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo la idea que te comenté, C++ es un lenguaje de instrucciones simples que puedes combinar para crear instrucciones más complejas.

No sabe cómo sumar todos los elementos de un arreglo, tienes que enseñarle.

Una de las formas es, creando una variable que lleve la cuenta (un acumulador), y recorriendo el arreglo sumando cada elemento al acumulador.

Para esto último necesitas un ciclo. Puedes usar el que quieras. Yo usaré un `for`, porque suele ser bastante práctico.

```
int numeros[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int total = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    total += numeros[i];
}
```

Es un código bastante simple.

Si no sabes por qué es así:

- El ciclo `for` consta de 3 partes y un cuerpo.
- La primera parte es de inicialización, porque se ejecuta antes de repetir e incluso de evaluar la condición.
- La segunda parte es la condición. El cuerpo se ejecutar una y otra vez mientras que sea verdadera.
- La tercera parte permite al ciclo avanzar. Puedes obtener un ciclo infinito si lo deseas, pero no es lo habitual ya que colgará el programa.
- Con el operador `[]` indicas con un entero el elemento al que quieres acceder o asignar.
- En el caso de `int numeros[]` no es un operador. Forma parte de la declaración de la variable y le indica al compilador que se trata de un arreglo.
- El primer elemento de un arreglo se encuentra en la posición `0`. De ahí que `i` comience en 0.
- Dándole algunas vueltas al punto anterior, si un arreglo tiene `N` elementos, la posición del último elemento es `N-1`. De ahí que la condición del for sea `i < 4`, ya que el ciclo se corta cuando `i == 4`.

---

Puedes aprovechar que esta es una tarea repetitiva y convertirlo en una función que devuelva la suma:

int sumatoria(int* arreglo, int n){
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
total += arreglo[i];
}
return total;
}

Y así esas 3 líneas de código se reducen a una más fácil de entender, llamando a una función.

Con los datos anteriores:

```
int numeros[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int total = sumatoria(numeros, 4);
```

---

Una vez llegado a este punto, deberías intuir que tu función debería tener esta pinta:

```
float MEDIA(DATOS &objdatos){
    float suma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        suma += objdatos.datos[i];
    }
    return suma / N;
}
```

---

A modo de comentario, sugiero que la función reciba una referencia constante si no tiene que modificar el objeto. De lo contrario no podrás llamar a la función si tienes el siguiente código:

```
DATOS datos(5);
datos.Leer_datos();

MEDIA(datos);
const DATOS &d = datos;
MEDIA(d); // Error de compilación
```

En cambio, si la función es así, no habrá ningún problema:

```
float MEDIA(const DATOS &objdatos){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!! ya tenia listo un for pero me mostraba un resultado sumamente erroneo
Ya pude ver mi error, muchisimas gracias!!